# Sonar flags reachable code as unreachable

Tags: c#, unit-testing, sonarqube

I have a piece of code in C# which looks as follows:

```
var results = new List<Result>();

var create = await _sender.Send<CreateResults>(createRequests, cancellationToken);
results.AddRange(create.Results);

var update = await _sender.Send<UpdateResults>(updateRequests, cancellationToken);
results.AddRange(update.Results);

if (results.Count == 0) // warning
{
    _logger.LogInformation("No requests were generated for the given set of requets");
    return;
}

// else make some other network calls
```

On the line `if (results.Count == 0)`, sonar gives me a warning `Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to 'False'. Some code paths are unreachable.`

I have tests for this line and it is possible for result.Count to be 0 because the request handlers may return an empty set of results for both create and update, in which case, The calls to `AddRange` basically do nothing and the list is still empty.

The reason this check exists is because we have some network calls after this which can be avoided if the results are empty.

If I wrap the returned value inside if blocks the error goes away, but why is it required as it does not really change the logic in any way?

```
var results = new List<Result>();

var create = await _sender.Send<CreateResults>(createRequests, cancellationToken);
if(create.Results.Any())
    results.AddRange(create.Results);

var update = await _sender.Send<UpdateResults>(updateRequests, cancellationToken);
if(update.Results.Any())
    results.AddRange(update.Results);

if (results.Count == 0) // no warnings generated
{
    _logger.LogInformation("No requests were generated for the given set of requets");
    return;
}

// else make some other network calls
```

Any insight on this matter will be helpful.

I have seen some other questions here on similar topic, but nothing that specifically about lists and counts.

Comment: Sounds like a SonarQube bug.

Answer (score 1):

It happens to me too. I've solved it by using `.Concat()` instead of `.AddRange()`.

In your case, it would be:

```
var create = await _sender.Send<CreateResults>(createRequests, cancellationToken);
    
var update = await _sender.Send<UpdateResults>(updateRequests, cancellationToken);

var results = create.Concat(update).ToList();
    
if (results.Count == 0) // warning
{
    _logger.LogInformation("No requests were generated for the given set of requets");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is definitely a good and cleaner work around than adding a bunch of unnecessary if statements, and this is what I eventually ended up implementing. However this does not really answer the original question as to why the warning comes in the first place.